# Oxford comma before "or"?

Tags: commas, conjunctions, oxford-comma, and-or

Is the Oxford comma restricted to the use of *"and"*? Or can/should it be also applied in sentences with *"or"*?

> 1. I would choose physics, mathematics or biology.
> 2. I would choose physics, mathematics, or biology.

Comment: number 2, always use the oxford comma.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma

Comment: @Yeshe 'Opinions among writers and editors differ on whether to use the serial comma.' (Wikipedia) ... 'This practice is controversial and is known as the serial comma or Oxford comma, because it is part of the house style of Oxford University Press.' However, The Oxford University guidelines ... for staff writing press releases and internal communications ... have dropped the recommendation that the comma be used (except where not to do so would give rise to ambiguity). You seem to have a higher authority. But what it is, I'm not sure.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, the reason it is a comment and not an answer is because it *is* an opinion. While I do appreciate your saying I have a higher authority (in this or in general) I don't understand how you would have deduced this. So to sum up your stance: "No answer".

Comment: @Yashe Don't phrase opinions as if they were binding rules.

Comment: I think **you** *should* be consistent. If you use an **oxford comma** then *always* use it. Otherwise, *never* use it. Except if it's a direct quote.

Comment: @Elliott Frisch Certain style guides recommend its use solely where it disambiguates.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Which is of course an absolutely nonsensical recommendation to begin with, since neither presence nor absence of a serial comma generally does nothing to augment or attenuate the ambiguity inherently present in any series in written form. Adding a serial comma to ‘disambiguate’ simply introduces a different ambiguity. They might as well recommend that you should only use _-ise_ to disambiguate. While it’s true that some style guides do give this useless recommendation, Elliott’s recommendation (given, after all, as only his own) is a lot more sane and meaningful.

Comment: @Janus It disambiguates with _I must tell my parents, John and Sally_ vs  _I must tell my parents, John, and Sally_ (and the style guides in question recommend that the comma be inserted as necessary, not arbitrarily, in such cases).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Of course, in some cases the alternative ambiguity it introduces is more unlikely than in other cases. It’s not very likely (though not impossible, either, I suppose) that someone would refer to their parents as simply “John”, but the ambiguity is still there in theory. And if the text in general does not use the serial comma, adding it in a case like that could easily distract the reader and make them think that the writer **is** actually referring to their parents as “John”. If you’re relying on a serial comma to disambiguate, you’re generally better off recasting.

Comment: @Janus But you're arguing here against what quite a few people actually do. Getting close to prescriptivism. OP asks 'can' as well as 'should' (and the latter becomes 'too opinion based' in my opinion).

Comment: @Edwin Well, not in my personal experience. (More or less) consistently either using or not using serial commas is far more common in my frame of reference. But anyway, I’m not prescribing anythign—people can punctuate however they like. I’m simply saying that any disambiguating benefit of introducing a serial comma only in certain cases is easily offset by the added unclarity of introducing a comma that you don’t normally use in your writing. And in cases where there really is actual ambiguity, relying on a comma to disambiguate is rarely an ideal solution.

Comment: @Janus But you have to be ready to deal with what other people do. And for a lot of people, "I must tell my parents, John and Sally" and "I must tell my parents, John, and Sally" have different meanings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The comments so far haven't answered your question.  There's quite an extensive explanation of the ins and outs of the Oxford or serial comma [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_comma).

You'll notice that the writer of the article says that "a serial comma or series comma (also called Oxford comma and Harvard comma) is a comma placed immediately before the coordinating conjunction (usually **and, or, or nor**) in a series of three or more terms."

So in answer to your question, the Oxford comma is not restricted to *and*.

Comment: Not being a native speaker I was a little too much impressed by the amount of information in this Wikipedia article. Thanks for pointing out the important points.